# relatedLists in VisualForce giving error 'Object' not a child relationship to 'object'

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two objects Loan__c and LoanedAmount__c. LoanedAmount__c has a lookup field to Loan__c. So in the Loan View page i am trying to create a VF page and adding a relatedlist.

`<apex:relatedList list="LoanedAmount__r">` does not seem to be working, as i get an error saying `LoanedAmount__r is not a child relationship to Loan`. What is the proper syntax?And is there a different syntax if it were a Master-Detail Relationship?

Answer (score 4):

If you look on the LoanedAmount_*c object page, and click on the field "Loan*_c" you will see the child relationship name there.

This is usually the plural of the object name, e.g. LoanedAmounts__r.

It can be something different for example if you have several lookups to the same object, and it's often different for lookups to User object.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check child relationship name?
By default this relation name is child object name + 's'.
I guess that it is possible that you make typo in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might work

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!LoanedAmount__r}"  />
```

What is the Controller for this Page ?

Comment: standard controller

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get the correct name for this.

Open up Eclipse -> Open up the Schema Browser in Eclipse -> Expand Loan -> Expand Child Relationships -> Expand your custom object -> Expand Fields -> Check 'Name'

This will build a query in your query results, and give you the correct relationship name.